# Where are formatter profiles stored in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Where are formatter profiles stored in Eclipse? I know how to export them, but how can I figure out the path of the currently used one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile is saved as part of the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` preferences file in the workspace `.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory.

This is basically a normal Java Properties file, but the contents is very messy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is my understanding right, that after you import a profile and make changes, it does not change the imported one but the one you mentioned above. So for my version control system the workflow would be for example:
1) put formatter.xml e.g. in cfg/formatter
2) make changes via UI in Eclipse and save
3) export and overwrite formatter.xml
4) commit changes in version control system

Comment: Sorry if the questions is kind of dumb, but I was expecting one can import/link the original file and make changes and commit them just like that.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to import and export. The exported file is just XML but there isn't any documentation on the contents, although it does use fairly clear names. In any case checking in anything in the .metadata is not recommended as it may not work on a different system.